# Ejecutando DLL con array como input desde VBA: error 91Variable de objeto o bloque with no establecido

Tags: vba, matlab, dll

He escrito un código en VBA para que ejecute una DLL creada mediante Matlab. La función de Matlab   convertida en DLL tiene como input un structure array de varios tipos de datos (números, texto, ruta). He referenciado bien la librería DLL en VBA y mi intención con este código es lanzar la DLL al pulsar un botón leyendo los datos desde una hoja Excel y metiéndolos en un array para usarlo como parámetro de entrada al llamar a la DLL. El código que se ejecuta al pulsar el botón se encuentra en "Sub Boton_Lanzar_Calculo()"

Este es el código:

```
Dim MCLUtil As Object
Dim bModuleInitialized As Boolean
Dim aClass As VictorCalc_main.Class1


''' Include a call to InitModule at the beginning to ensure that the initialization alwais gets performed as needed
Private Sub InitModule()
   If Not bModuleInitialized Then
      On Error GoTo Handle_Error
      If MCLUtil Is Nothing Then
         Set MCLUtil = CreateObject("MWComUtil.MWUtil")
      End If
      Call MCLUtil.MWInitApplication(Application)
      bModuleInitialized = True
      Exit Sub
Handle_Error:
      bModuleInitialized = False
   End If
End Sub

'New operator:
Function recorrido(ByVal inputscript As Variant) As Variant
       
       On Error GoTo Handle_Error
       Set aClass = New VictorCalc_main.Class1
       aClass = CreateObject("VictorCalc_main.Class1.1_0")
       Call aClass.recorrido(inputscript)
       Exit Function
Handle_Error:
   recorrido = Err.Description
End Function
 
 Sub Boton_Lanzar_Calculo()
 
   Dim inputscript() As Variant

   ReDim inputscript(11)

   inputscript(0) = Range("Sentido")
   inputscript(1) = Range("Paso_tiempo")
   inputscript(2) = Range("Paso_posición")
   inputscript(3) = Range("Ruta_Archivo_Input")
   inputscript(4) = Range("Nombre_archivo_output")
   inputscript(5) = Range("Flag_tabla_límite_aceleración")
   inputscript(6) = Range("Flag_tabla_rendimiento_motor")
   inputscript(7) = Range("Flag_guardar_Excel")
   inputscript(8) = Range("Tipo_resistencia_rodante")
   inputscript(9) = Range("Tipo_resistencia_por_pendiente")
   inputscript(10) = Range("Tipo_resistencia_por_curva")
  
  Call aClass.recorrido(inputscript)
   
 End Sub
```

El error lo da al hacer el call a la función recorrido con el array inputscript. ¿Puede ser que no acepte los datos que quiero pasar a la DLL?

Comment: Bienvenido. Esos Range que metes en cada inputscript ¿donde los declaras?. Para asignar un rango a una variable tipo Variant debes declarar primero el rango: Set rngSentido = Range("A1:B6") y luego en el inputscrtipt poner algo como: inputscript(0) = rngSentido.

ÉChale un ojo.

Comment: Declaro las variables asignando nombres  a las celdas en los que están los valores que quiero meter en el array inputscript, después llamo directamente a esas celdas mediante Range("Nombre asignado a la celda"). Probaré haciéndolo como comentas. Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Lo he probado delarando los Range de diferente manera pero se mantiene el error, también lo he probado creando un array de tipo integer solo con valores numéricos y me da el mismo error, alguna otra idea del porque puede ser además del tipo de dato del array?